# Poincare plot in Python - fitting the ellipse?

Tags: python, numpy, plot, curve-fitting

I have a time series `X` and have plotted `X(t)` against `X(t-1)`. I need to fit and ellipse to the data, and then plot the minor (`SD1`) and major (`SD2`) axes of the fitted ellipse to produce a poincare plot.

Does anybody know how to do this in Python, using numpy/scikit/Pandas?

Comment: There's a good discussion of this problem [here](http://nicky.vanforeest.com/misc/fitEllipse/fitEllipse.html)